# How to search file and return a value with Java?

Tags: java, file, loops, while-loop, return

I need some help with the code below.
What I'm trying to do is read data out of lines in a file.
The way I thought of doing this was to use a while loop to iterate through the lines to try and find a specific "x_y_z" and use the indexOf() method to see if it exists. So basically I want to run my loop until I get a value that isn't -1, and then break the loop and return that value. I'm having trouble returning the value...I don't seem to be able to get it out of the loop. Can anyone help me here?

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

/**
 *
 * @author Tim
 */
public class ReadIn {

    public static int read(String path, int x, int y, int z, Player player) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(path);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;

            //Read File Line By Line
            int index = -1;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null && index == -1) {
                index = strLine.indexOf(x + "_" + y + "_" + z);
                if (index != -1) {
                    int value = index;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //Close the input stream
            in.close();

        } catch (Exception exception) {//Catch exception if any
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much,
Tim

Comment: Does this compile?  I don't see that you are returning a value from the read method.

Comment: No, it doesn't compile. My problem was me asking where I should put the return statement to make it compile...sorry I wasn't so clear on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code does not compile, the method does not return any value! 
Do this instead:

```
    public static int read(String path, int x, int y, int z, Player player) {
        int value = -1;
        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(path);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine = "";       
            //Read File Line By Line
            int index = -1;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                index = strLine.indexOf(x + "_" + y + "_" + z);
                if (index != -1) {
                    value = index;
                    break;
                }
            }
            //Close the input stream
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {//Catch exception if any
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Value will now contain the correct index, -1 otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering where that return statement should have gone.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem

```
public class ReadIn {

    public static int read(String path, int x, int y, int z, Player player) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(path);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;

            int value = -1;
            //Read File Line By Line
            int index = -1;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                index = strLine.indexOf(x + "_" + y + "_" + z);
                if (index != -1) {
                    value = index;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //Close the input stream
            in.close();
            return value;

        } catch (Exception exception) {//Catch exception if any
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems.. First of all there is no return in your function so this wouldn't even compile.
Second of all you are return an index which corresponds to the location of some line in the file where it found that string. Wouldn't it be better to return the entire line of text?
I would put the return from the function right when you find the value though, instead of using break.

Sorry I now see why you aren't returning from within the loop. However you could still do that if you put a finally in your function

-- Updated to remove multiple exit points --

-- Fixed variable declaration so it has scope in finally --

-- Alright I think it should compile now --

```
public class ReadIn {

public static int read(String path, int x, int y, int z, Player player)  {
    DataInputStream in = null;
    int index = -1;
    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(path);
        in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        //Read File Line By Line            
        while (index == -1 && (strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            index = strLine.indexOf(x + "_" + y + "_" + z);
        }
        in.close(); 
    } catch (Exception exception) {//Catch exception if any
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: For my purposes all I want is the location of where it found the string. And thanks, my question was pertaining to where the return statement should go.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the help. I think I'll look into learning about finally.

Comment: @Matt Wolfe, Avoid multiple exit points in your code as much as possible :)